# serialized string from ASP.NET to jquery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, serialization, deserialization

i need to pass image paths to jquery from asp.net using hidden field
i want to serialize paths like 
"www.asd.com/asd.png ||| www.asd.com/asd2.png"

and reach them in jquery like

var pathStrings;

var blabla = pathStrings[i];

how can i do that?

thank you.

Comment: You are setting these values in a delimited hidden field and want to access them in javascript array?

Comment: Those image paths come from your database? Or do you set the client side?

Comment: the paths come from database and i want to reach them in javascript array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like this is what you're looking for

```
var hiddenFieldVal = $('#HiddenFieldID').val();
var pathStrings = hiddenFieldVal.split(' ||| ');
var blabla = pathStrings[i];
```

Comment: this does looks like what i am looking for.I will try this out now.